# Is there a limit to how many changes to the DOM that can occur in a single JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am writing a **JavaScript** function to hide and show various elements on a web page using the `onclick=function()` event, but there are a many elements that I am trying to hide/show.

I have tried doing it both using `document.getElementByID()` as well as `document.getElementByClassName()`, and neither one is working. While it appears that the `onclick="()"` event is being triggered, it does not appear to be affected. Could this be because I am trying to manipulate multiple elements?

Here is the code:

```
function p1() 
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("prof").style.display = '' ; 
    document.getElementsByClassName("service").style.display = 'none' ; 
    document.getElementsByClassName("scholar").style.display = 'none' ; 
    document.getElementsByClassName("brother").style.display = 'none' ; 
}

function s1()
{
    document.getElementById('professionalism_section').style.display = 'none' ; 
    document.getElementById('prof_head').style.display = 'none' ; 
    document.getElementById('prof_pic').style.display = 'none' ;
    document.getElementById('prof_image').style.display = 'none' ; 
    document.getElementById('prof_desc').style.display = 'none' ; 

    document.getElementById('service_section').style.display = 'block' ; 
    document.getElementById('service_head').style.display = 'block' ;
    document.getElementById('service_pic').style.display = 'block' ;
    document.getElementById('service_image').style.display = 'block' ; 
    document.getElementById('service_desc').style.display = 'block' ;

    document.getElementById('scholarship_section').style.display = 'none' ;
    document.getElementById('scholarship_head').style.display = 'none' ;
    document.getElementById('scholarship_pic').style.display = 'none' ;
    document.getElementById('scholarship_image').style.display = 'none' ; 
    document.getElementById('scholarship_desc').style.display = 'none' ;

    document.getElementById('brotherhood_section').style.display = 'none' ;
    document.getElementById('brotherhood_head').style.display = 'none' ;
    document.getElementById('brotherhood_pic').style.display = 'none' ;
    document.getElementById('brotherhood_image').style.display = 'none' ; 
    document.getElementById('brotherhood_service_desc').style.display = 'none' ;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: paste your html here

Comment: Function p1 won't work because you'd have to iterate through the collection of elements.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to web design.... what do you mean iterate through the collection of elements?

Answer (score 0):

The first line won't work and it can prevent your entire script from running.         `document.getElementsByClassName("prof").style.display = '' ;` try something like document.getElementsById("prof").style.display = 'none' ;

Your html is missing. I'm wondering why you are trying to hide a css class in such a manner.

Comment: I tried adding 

document.getElementByID("prof").style.display = 'block';

but I had no success.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a counter var and increment it each time you change the DOM, then check that the value of counter is not above your threshold before executing any dom changes.

Comment: Do you have an example for what you mean?

Comment: Not really sure if it will work, but with JQuery you could set `var x = 0;`
Before making a DOM change, do `if (x < myThreshold){ ..DOM change.. }`
Then after the DOM change, do `x++;`

Comment: No problem! Please mark this as answered and update your question with the solution when you get a chance